# Gradient colors for faces of surface

Tags: matlab, 3d, data-visualization, matlab-figure, surface

I have the following code for MATLAB:

```
close all
clear all
clc
edges= linspace(0,1,10);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(edges);
Z=rand(10);
h= surf(X,Y,Z,'FaceColor','none')
```

I need to paint the faces on this surface. The face with coordinate (0,0) should be green and the face with coordinate(1,1) should be red. All faces on diagonal should be yellow.

**Could You help me to perform this painting?**

Comment: hmmm ... you have vertices and faces in 3D but you specify only 2 coordinates in your constraints ("_The face with coordinate (0,0) should be green_") ... Are you talking about the `X,Y` coordinates ?? Also, `vertices` (=points) have unique coordinates, `faces` have multiple coordinates (they are linked by several points), so if you want a criteria for coloring your `faces`, then point coordinates is not the best choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a closer look at the [`surf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) command, you'll see, that you can set a custom "colormap", which is then used instead of the `Z` data as a color indicator.

So, you just have to set up a proper "colormap". That one must have the same dimensions as your `X` and `Y` data, and for each data point you must specify the `[R, G, B]` triplet of your choice, i.e. `[0, 1, 0]` for the `[0, 0]` coordinate, `[1, 0, 0]` for the `[1, 1]` coordinate, and some "diagonal" interpolation between those two.

Luckily, you already have that, have a look at your `X` and `Y` data! Adding both will give that kind of "diagonal" interpolation for the green channel. The inverse of that will give the proper red channel. (The scaling is a bit corrupt, since you have values larger than `1.0`, but these will "clipped".)

Here's the enhanced code:

```matlab
edges = linspace(0, 1, 10);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(edges);
Z = rand(10);
cm(:, :, 1) = (X + Y);          % Red channel
cm(:, :, 2) = 2 - cm(:, :, 1);  % Green channel
cm(:, :, 3) = zeros(size(X));   % Blue channel (empty)
h = surf(X, Y, Z, cm);          % No need for the FaceColor property
```

The output looks like this:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

One way would be the following:

```
edges= linspace(0,1,10);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(edges);
Z=rand(10);


% Fake some color data
cdata = zeros(size(Z));

for i = 1:size(cdata,1)
    cdata(i,i) = i; 
end

%make a suitable colormap

cm = ones(size(cdata,1), 3);
cm = cm .*[ 1 1 0 ] % everything yellow
cm(1, :) = [1 1 1] % except for 0
cm(2, :) = [1 0 0] % except for 1
cm(end, :) = [0 1 0] % except for 10

ax = axes();
h = surface(ax, X,Y,Z);
h.CData = cdata;
ax.Colormap = cm;
```

[image]